# Glitch when creating transparent animated gifs

Tags: ffmpeg, animated-gif

I'm using FFMPEG to create an animated gif from a set of frames with transparency. First a palette is created.

```
input file: -f frameinput -input_type canvas -pix_fmt bgra -r 6 -s 640x360
output file: -vf palettegen=stats_mode=full -an
```

Then the gif is created.

```
input file: -f frameinput -input_type canvas -pix_fmt bgra -r 6 -s 640x360
output file: -f gif -lavfi paletteuse=diff_mode=rectangle:dither=none -an
```

The result looks like this. The issue occurs immediately after all transparent background areas are covered up with opaque regions.

[image]

It should look like the following. This was created by using the ezgif website.

[image]

Does anyone know what could be going on here? Are there any parameters I can include to prevent this? The resulting palette file looks correct, with all black apart from one transparent pixel in the bottom right, so I assume the issue is in the paletteuse call.

Things I have tried to fix the issue include changing the diff_mode and dither. Use_alpha looks like something I should try but I can't seem to get the syntax right. The user guide doesn't give an example and I can't find any examples anywhere else.

Comment: What version of FFMPEG are you using? This looks similar to a problem I introduce but was fixed, so the first thing I would try is getting the latest version of FFMPEG. (the problem and fix are described by my colleague, here: https://engineering.giphy.com/fixing-bugs-in-ffmpeg-gif-encoding/)

Comment: Many thanks for your response. I'm using FFMPEG version 4.4. I'm not sure that the issue is the same as the one you linked to. My issue occurs in a very specific situation only when it transitions from a frame with some transparency to a frame with none, as shown in my question. It's as if the code for tracking the transparent pixels gets confused when there are none.

Comment: Hmm, yes, that sounds different. I'm afraid I can't think of a workaround. You might have to dig into the code. :(

Comment: @BjornRoche, would you be able to test this in your own software to see if it's reproducible? I'm convinced now that this is a bug. Looking into the code it seems that the issue occurs after switching from gif_image_write_translucent to gif_image_write_opaque and is possibly related to disposal methods again. For now I have added a horrible fudge in my code to place a transparent pixel in the bottom right hand corner of all frames if creating a transparent gif. This ensures that the frames are never fully opaque.